# Android Firebase push notification automatic pop up

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am very new to android application development.I implemented the push notification for my app by using google firebase.So notification and comes in very accurate but the problem is its not pop up automatically.Is there is any way to pop up the notification?.After so many search i realized that use notification channels for achieve that ,but i didn't get any proper solution for that?Please any one help me?The answer will be appreciated.Here i provide notification.utils class that i am using.

```
Notification.utils

public class NotificationUtils {

private static String TAG = NotificationUtils.class.getSimpleName();

private Context mContext;

public NotificationUtils(Context mContext) {
    this.mContext = mContext;

}

public void showNotificationMessage(String title,String body, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent) {
    showNotificationMessage(title,body, message, timeStamp, intent, null);
}

public void showNotificationMessage(final String title,String body, final String message, final String timeStamp, Intent intent, String imageUrl) {
    // Check for empty push message
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(message))
        return;


    // notification icon
    final int icon = R.mipmap.ic_launcher;
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
   // Intent PendingIntent = new Intent(mContext, ChatActivity.class);
    final PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    mContext,
                    0,
                    intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
            );

    final NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            mContext);

    final Uri alarmSound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE
            + "://" + mContext.getPackageName() + "/raw/notification");

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(imageUrl)) {

        if (imageUrl != null && imageUrl.length() > 4 && Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(imageUrl).matches()) {

            Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromURL(imageUrl);

            if (bitmap != null) {
                showBigNotification(bitmap, mBuilder, icon, title,body, message, timeStamp, resultPendingIntent, alarmSound);
            } else {
                showSmallNotification(mBuilder, icon, title, message, timeStamp, resultPendingIntent, alarmSound);
            }
        }
    } else {
        showSmallNotification(mBuilder, icon, title, message, timeStamp, resultPendingIntent, alarmSound);
        playNotificationSound();
    }
}


private void showSmallNotification(NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder, int icon, String title, String body, String timeStamp, PendingIntent resultPendingIntent, Uri alarmSound) {

    NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
   // inboxStyle.addLine(message);
    Notification notification;
    notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(title)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
            .setSound(alarmSound)
            .setStyle(inboxStyle)
            .setWhen(getTimeMilliSec(timeStamp))
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), icon))
            .build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(Config.NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
}

private void showBigNotification(Bitmap bitmap, NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder, int icon, String title,String body, String message, String timeStamp, PendingIntent resultPendingIntent, Uri alarmSound) {
    NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle bigPictureStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();
    bigPictureStyle.setBigContentTitle(title);
    bigPictureStyle.setSummaryText(Html.fromHtml(message).toString());
    bigPictureStyle.bigPicture(bitmap);
    Notification notification;
    notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext, Constants.ProfileFragment.CHANNEL_ID).setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(title)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
            .setSound(alarmSound)
            .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), icon))
            .setContentText(body)
            .build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(Config.NOTIFICATION_ID_BIG_IMAGE, notification);
}

/**
 * Downloading push notification image before displaying it in
 * the notification tray
 */
public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String strURL) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(strURL);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

// Playing notification sound
public void playNotificationSound() {
    try {
        Uri alarmSound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE
                + "://" + mContext.getPackageName() + "/raw/notification");
        Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(mContext, alarmSound);
        r.play();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Method checks if the app is in background or not
 */
public static boolean isAppIsInBackground(Context context) {
    boolean isInBackground = true;
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcesses = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
        for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : runningProcesses) {
            if (processInfo.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
                for (String activeProcess : processInfo.pkgList) {
                    if (activeProcess.equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                        isInBackground = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
        ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
        if (componentInfo.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
            isInBackground = false;
        }
    }

    return isInBackground;
}

// Clears notification tray messages
public static void clearNotifications(Context context) {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.cancelAll();
}

public static long getTimeMilliSec(String timeStamp) {
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    try {
        Date date = format.parse(timeStamp);
        return date.getTime();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return 0;
}
}

 2. MyFirebaseMessagingService.class
 public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
public  int total=0;
private static final String TAG = MyFirebaseMessagingService.class.getSimpleName();

private NotificationUtils notificationUtils;
int badge;

public static final String NOTIFICATION_REPLY = "NotificationReply";
public static final String CHANNNEL_ID = "Bawabba";
public static final String CHANNEL_NAME = "Bawabba";


public static final String KEY_INTENT_MORE = "keyintentmore";
public static final String KEY_INTENT_HELP = "keyintenthelp";

public static final int REQUEST_CODE_MORE = 100;
public static final int REQUEST_CODE_HELP = 101;
public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 200;

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Log.e(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
    System.out.println("Arjun from : " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
    System.out.println("Arjun toSt : " + remoteMessage.toString());

    System.out.println("Arjun :: handleNotification");
    total = ObjectFactory.getInstance().getAppPreference(getApplicationContext()).getUnreadMessage();
    System.out.println("Arjun :: totalUNREADmessage " + total);
    total++;
    ObjectFactory.getInstance().getAppPreference(getApplicationContext()).saveUnreadMessage(total);
    ObjectFactory.getInstance().getAppPreference(getApplicationContext()).saveNewMessageArrived(true);


    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new  NotificationCompat.Builder(this,CHANNNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getData().get("title"))
            .setContentText(remoteMessage.getData().get("body"))
            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setAutoCancel(true);


    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    manager.notify(123, builder.build());

    if (remoteMessage == null)
        return;

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        handleNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        handleNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());
    }
    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
        remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();

        Log.e(TAG, "Data Payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());
        badge = Integer.parseInt(remoteMessage.getData().get("badge"));
        Log.e("notificationNUmber",":"+badge);
        // setBadge(getApplicationContext(), badge);

        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData().toString());
            handleDataMessage(json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        String id = "id_product";
        // The user-visible name of the channel.
        CharSequence name = "Bawabba";
        // The user-visible description of the channel.
        String description = remoteMessage.getData().get("body");
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
        @SuppressLint("WrongConstant") NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(id, name, importance);
        // Configure the notification channel.
        mChannel.setDescription(description);
        mChannel.enableLights(true);
        // Sets the notification light color for notifications posted to this
        // channel, if the device supports this feature.
        mChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
    }


}
private void handleNotification(String message) {
    try {
        if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
            // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
            Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
            pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

            // play notification sound
            NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
            notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();
            EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageEvent("Comes from showUnreadMessages!"));
        } else {
            // If the app is in background, firebase itself handles the notification
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Arjun :: error " + e.getMessage());
    }
}


private void handleDataMessage(JSONObject json) {

    Log.e(TAG, "push json: " + json.toString());

    try {
        JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");
        String title = data.getString("title");
        String body = data.getString("body");
        String message = data.getString("message");
        boolean isBackground = data.getBoolean("is_background");
        String imageUrl = data.getString("image");
        String timestamp = data.getString("timestamp");
        JSONObject payload = data.getJSONObject("payload");

        Log.e(TAG, "title: " + title);
        Log.e(TAG, "body: " + body);
        Log.e(TAG, "message: " + message);
        Log.e(TAG, "isBackground: " + isBackground);
        Log.e(TAG, "payload: " + payload.toString());
        Log.e(TAG, "imageUrl: " + imageUrl);
        Log.e(TAG, "timestamp: " + timestamp);


        if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
            // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
            Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
            pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
            pushNotification.putExtra("title", title);
            pushNotification.putExtra("body", body);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

            // play notification sound
            NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
            notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();
        } else {
            // app is in background, show the notification in notification tray
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ChatActivity.class);
            resultIntent.putExtra("message", message);

            // check for image attachment
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(imageUrl)) {
                showNotificationMessage(getApplicationContext(), title,body, message, timestamp, resultIntent);
            } else {
                // image is present, show notification with image
                showNotificationMessageWithBigImage(getApplicationContext(), title,body, message,timestamp,resultIntent, imageUrl);
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Json Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }

}

private void showNotificationMessage(Context context, String title, String body, String message,String timeStamp, Intent intent) {
    notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(context);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title,body ,message, timeStamp, intent);
}

private void showNotificationMessageWithBigImage(Context context, String title,String body, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent, String imageUrl) {
    notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(context);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title,body, message, timeStamp, intent, imageUrl);
}
}
```

Comment: add code for the notification service. this is helper class only

Comment: I added the firebase messaging service also.Pls check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Notifications, you are required to set a vibrate or ringtone to make Heads-up work. However, here's a quick hack that doesn't require VIBRATE permission to produce a head-up notification:

```
notificationBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) notificationBuilder.setVibrate(new long[0]);
```

1. because of under lollipop not working Hands-up Notification Android
2. Don't abuse heads-up notification. See here for when to use heads-up notification:
3. MAX: For critical and urgent notifications that alert the user to a condition that is time-critical or needs to be resolved before they can continue with a particular task.
4. HIGH: Primarily for important communication, such as messages or chat events with content that is particularly interesting for the user. High-priority notifications trigger the heads-up notification display.

> MAX Use for critical and urgent notifications that alert the user to a condition that is time-critical or needs to be resolved before they can continue with a particular task.
>
> HIGH Use primarily for important communication, such as message or chat events with content that is particularly interesting for the user. High-priority notifications trigger the heads-up notification display.
>
> DEFAULT Use for all notifications that don't fall into any of the other priorities described here and if the application does not prioritize its own notifications
>
> LOW Use for notifications that you want the user to be informed about, but that are less urgent. Low-priority notifications tend to show up at the bottom of the list, which makes them a good choice for things like public or undirected social updates: The user has asked to be notified about them, but these notifications should never take precedence over urgent or direct communication.
>
> MIN Use for contextual or background information such as weather information or contextual location information. Minimum-priority notifications do not appear in the status bar. The user discovers them on expanding the notification shade.

Comment: Thanks its working when app is in foreground mode.but not in background.

Comment: @Arjun please check below code I think it may be work for you and also if you need more help then comment here i will always here, Happy coding...

Answer (score 0):

If an app is in the background then you need to manage state for background and foreground

1 You chack app state via below condition

```
  public static boolean isAppIsInBackground(Context context) {
    boolean isInBackground = true;
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcesses = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
        for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : runningProcesses) {
            if (processInfo.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
                for (String activeProcess : processInfo.pkgList) {
                    if (activeProcess.equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                        isInBackground = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
        ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
        if (componentInfo.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
            isInBackground = false;
        }
    }

    return isInBackground;
}
```

After that, you can check condition in push notification class

```
 if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
            // app is in the foreground, broadcast the push message

        } else {
            // app is in background, show the notification in notification tray                             
          showNotificationMessage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, timestamp, resultIntent);                                                       
            }
```

then after apply below code......

```
 public void showNotificationMessage(final String title, final String message, final String timeStamp, Intent intent, String imageUrl) {
    // Check for empty push message
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(message))
        return;


    // notification icon
    final int icon = R.mipmap.noti_logo;
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.setAction(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    final PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    final NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext);
    final Uri alarmSound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE+ "://" + mContext.getPackageName() + "/raw/notification");*/

    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

     showSmallNotification(mBuilder, icon, title, message, timeStamp, resultPendingIntent, alarmSound);

}

 private void showSmallNotification(NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder, int icon, String title, String message, String timeStamp, PendingIntent resultPendingIntent, Uri alarmSound) {

    NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();

    inboxStyle.addLine(message);

    Notification notification;
    notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(title)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
            .setStyle(inboxStyle)
            .setSound(alarmSound)
            .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000})
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.noti_logo)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), icon))
            .setContentText(message)
            .build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID++;
}
```

---

IF IT NOT WORK THEN USE BELOW ONCE ALSO WITH CHECK APP BACKGROUND APP CONDITION

---

```
private void test() {
Intent intent;
intent = new Intent(this, SplashScreenActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putBoolean("isDisplayAlert", true);
bundle.putString("NOTIFICATION_DATA", "data");
intent.putExtras(bundle);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),
        new Random().nextInt(), intent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_location)
        .setContentTitle("Title")
        .setContentText("Body")
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
        .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
        .setFullScreenIntent(pendingIntent, true);

NotificationManager notificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

notificationBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);
notificationBuilder.setVibrate(new long[0]);
notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());                                                   
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for ur consideration.The first solution is not work and i got confused where to use the second solution that you gave.